# Error in messenger during composer update symfony

Tags: composer-php, symfony4

I am trying to update my symfony installation from 4.1.7 but I receive the following error in my console:

> In MessenegerPass.php line 279: Invalid middleware: service
>   "allow_no_handler" not found.

Here is my composer.json

```
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "msgphp/user": "^0.7.0",
    "msgphp/user-bundle": "^0.7.0",
    "oneup/uploader-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/asset": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.6",
    "symfony/form": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/messenger": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.5",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/process": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/validator": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.9",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "*",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.2.*"
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "4.2.*"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

messsenger.yaml

```
    # see 

 https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/messenger/4.1/config/packages/messenger.yaml
     framework:
       messenger:
          transports:
             # Uncomment the following line to enable a transport named "amqp"
             # amqp: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'

        routing:
            # Route your messages to the transports
            # 'App\Message\YourMessage': amqp

        default_bus: command_bus
        buses:
            command_bus:
                middleware:
                    - msgphp.messenger.console_message_receiver
            event_bus:
                middleware:
                    - msgphp.messenger.console_message_receiver
                    - allow_no_handler

    services:
        msgphp.messenger.command_bus: '@command_bus'
        msgphp.messenger.event_bus: '@event_bus'
```

I tried also deleting composer.lock but still I get the same results.
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your messenger yml file?

Comment: Sure @Albeis, I edited the question by adding the messenger.yaml

Comment: Have you tried use 'allow_no_handlers'  instead?

Comment: @Albeis How can I use it? Should I look for it somewhere?

Comment: Try replacing "allow_no_handler" on you yml to "allow_no_handlers". But that value, should be on 'default_middleware'...try to remove 'allow_no_handler' Check: https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger/multiple_buses.html

Comment: @Albeis thank you for your suggestion. After changing the yaml file in 4.2 version I get this error on my console and website: "Compile Error: Declaration of MsgPhp\Domain\Infra\Messenger\Middleware\ConsoleMessageReceiverMiddleware::handle($message, callable $next) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Messenger\Middleware\MiddlewareInterface::handle(Symfony\Component\Messenger\Envelope $envelope, Symfony\Component\Messenger\Middleware\StackInterface $stack): Symfony\Component\Messenger\Envelope"

Comment: looks like you are not implementing MiddlewareInterface on your console_message_receiver ... may it be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206304/discussion-between-dimitris-markopoulos-and-albeis).